# I can't make a change on my web site after successfully deployed.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I successfully deployed my rails app on heroku and launched officially but can't make a change to my rails app. I run `git push heroku` after I edited html code but nothing changed on home page.
I get below when I run `git push heroku`

```
everything up to date
```

I'm sure I run `git add .`, `git commit` before `git push heroku`.  Does anyone know why? I need your help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're on the master branch which Heroku uses to deploy your app. So run `git checkout master` before adding and committing your file. Then use `git push heroku master` to deploy.

Comment: I get Already on 'master'. Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.